# PhantomJS not retrieving correct data

Tags: javascript, python, beautifulsoup, phantomjs

I am trying to scrape a web page which has javascript in it using phantomjs. I found an element for button and when i click it, it show render next link. But i am not getting the exact output what i want. Instead, i am getting different output which is not required.

The code is:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
s = requests.session()
fg =s.get('https://in.bookmyshow.com/booktickets/INCM/32076',headers=headers)
so = BeautifulSoup(fg.text,"html.parser")
texts = so.findAll("div",{"class":"__buytickets"})
print(texts[0].a['href'])
print(fg.url)
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get(movie_links[0])
element = driver.find_element_by_class_name('__buytickets')
element.click()
print(driver.current_url)
```

I am getting the output as :

```
javascript:;
https://in.bookmyshow.com/booktickets/INCM/32076
https://in.bookmyshow.com/booktickets/INVB/47680
```

what i have to get is:

```
javascript:;
https://in.bookmyshow.com/booktickets/INCM/32076
https://in.bookmyshow.com/booktickets/INCM/32076#Seatlayout
```

Actually, the link which i have to get is generated by javascript of the previous link. How to get this link? (seatlayout link) Please help! Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I suggest that you use the Mozilla or Chrome drivers so that you can view the pages in a browser. Then use a debugger, such as the one that comes with PyCharm, and set a breakpoint. Then you can step through your code and manually inspect the web elements of the page that loads.

Comment: Where do you define `s`?

Comment: The thing is, browser should not opened. It takes so much time when compared to this

Comment: After you have a working program that will run without error, then you can change it back to headless without a browser. But speed has no meaning if the code is not correct. You can run as fast as you want and you will still get the wrong answer...only more quickly.

Comment: sorry, i didnt add session() code, now i added it

Comment: What you said is also correct. I will try that @Code-Apprentice

Comment: I am getting correct output using selenium. But not with phantomjs

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Can you show a [mcve] including the two variations you are using?

Comment: I tried with selenium, I am able to get the correct url after clicking the button, But when I try the same with phantomJS, it is not working

Comment: Please provide code examples to show what you tried. We cannot help you from just a verbal description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PhantomJS in my experience don't work well.
Сhrome and Mozilla better.
Vitaly Slobodin https://github.com/Vitallium said he will not develop more Phantomjs.

Use Headless Chrome or Firefox.